# How to deal with a large mySQL tree

Tags: php, mysql, database, tree

I am working on a project which user registration multiples like this.
1st Month   -> 1 user
2nd Month   -> 4 users comes under the above user
3rd Month   -> 16 users (i.e, 4 users comes under each 4 users above )
4th Month   -> 64 users (i.e, 4 users comes under each 16 users above )

eg:
          1
            2 | 2
            8 | 8
           32| 32

and continues...

Please give me an advice, how to store this in database.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `user_id` is your primary key, create a `parent` column that contains the `user_id` of the parent user. For example:

```
user_id  parent
1        NULL
2        1
3        1
4        1
5        1
6        2
...
```

You will also want to create an index on the `parent` column so that you can quickly do a reverse lookup (i.e. find all children of a given user).